# How to get a value from div without write some event (onclick,etc) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some question about how to get some value from some element like div,etc using jquery and without write onclick event or etc on the div where I want to get that value.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" title="test1">test</div>
    <div id="test2" title="test2">test2</div>
    <script>
        function getVal(attr,value){
            $("#show").text("this "+attr+" have value ="+value);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test").click(function(){
                getVal("#test",$("#test").attr("title"));
            }); 
        });
    </script>
    <div id="show"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Usually to get some value from div that i click, I add an onclick event on div like 
`<div id='test' onclick="getVal(test)" ></div>` 
and it will return "test". And the code that I write above nearly what I want, but the problem that I have is if I have a many div, how can I get the value from each div that I click just using jquery click function and I don't need to write

```
$("#test").click(function(){
                    getVal("#test",$("#test").attr("title"));
                }); 
$("#test2").click(function(){
                    getVal("#test2",$("#test2").attr("title"));
                });//and so on
```

here the code that I use to achieve what I want, using onclick event that I put on div:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function overlay(rel){
                    var value = rel;
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".img"+value).click(function(){
                            $(".overlay-bg"+value).fadeIn();
                        });
                        $(".close"+value).click(function(){
                            $(".overlay-bg"+value).fadeOut();
                        })
                    });
                }
            </script>
        <div id="gallery">

                                <img src="http://localhost/wedding/source/gallery/thumb/thumb-a.jpg" class="img1" onclick="overlay(1)" title="photo1" alt="photo1"/> 

                            </div>

                            <div id="overlay-bg" class="overlay-bg1">

                                <div id="overlay"><img src="http://localhost/wedding/source/gallery/a.jpg"/>

                                    <span>photo1</span>

                                    <span style="font-size:0.8em;"><p>photo a</p></span>

                                    <div id="close" class="close1"></div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

<div id="gallery">

                                <img src="http://localhost/wedding/source/gallery/thumb/thumb-b.jpg" class="img2" onclick="overlay(2)" title="photo2" alt="photo2"/> 

                            </div>

                            <div id="overlay-bg" class="overlay-bg2">

                                <div id="overlay"><img src="http://localhost/wedding/source/gallery/b.jpg"/>

                                    <span>photo2</span>

                                    <span style="font-size:0.8em;"><p>photo b</p></span>

                                    <div id="close" class="close2"></div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
```

I'm really want to know how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Give the elements you want to attach the click event handler to the same class. Then use the [class selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select all of them:

```
$('.sharedClass').click(function() {
    getVal(this.id, $(this).attr("title"));
});
```

jQuery will bind the event handler to each of the selected elements.

[There are many ways to select elements *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors), selection by ID or class are just two of them. You might also find the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) useful to get a better idea of how jQuery works.

Comment: ow, i get it.. let me to try that.. thx for your answer Felix..:D

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `this` keyword within the handler function, and it will point to the element that was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to do it.

Put a class name to your target `div` e.g.

```
<div id="test" class="clickable" title="test">test</div>
<div id="test2" class="clickable" title="test">test</div>
...
...
```

Then create a jQuery event with selected `class`

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">harsh</div>


<script>
alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this function with the click of every div, use :

```
 $("div").click(function(){
                getVal($(this),$(this).attr("title"));
            });
```

If you want to call the function for a set of divs, but not all, give those divs a class name as suggested by @Felix Kling.

Check out the [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get a better idea.

Comment: You're welcome. Accept an answer, whichever worked for you. Also, vote up and down relevant answers. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve.

If you have multiple values how do you want to store them?

If you have an array that you wanted to populate you can use the each() function on a JQuery selector to traverse all elements selected.

Like so:

```
    var values = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test1, #test2').each(function(){
            values.push($(this).html());
        });
    });
```

You could also store the values in an associative way to make retrieval a bit easier if you didn't want to iterate through an array. For example you could use the value of the 'title' attribute as the key in the array.

Replace the values.push() line with this line of code:

```
values[$(this).attr('title')] = $(this).html();
```

Comment: like felix said, i can use class selector to store them. But thx for your answer too, i don't think to use array in jquery before..

Comment: I agree. A class selector would be cleaner than chaining a bunch # id's.